# Label styled-components classNames

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

With `styled-components`, the DOM nodes classNames are shown in a similar fashion:

[image]

Is there a way to distinguish them with proper names on development environment for better debugging?

Comment: you can read this: https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#better-debugging

Comment: Any way this can be achieved without ejecting the app, when created through `CRA`?

Comment: for CRA, it should be easier, just use `styled-components/macro` : https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#babel-macro

Comment: Ahh nicee, thank you!